# Internationalisation - displaying gendered adjectives

Tags: internationalization

I'm currently working on an internationalisation project for a large web application - initially we're just implementing French but more languages will follow in time. One of the issues we've come across is how to display adjectives.

Let's take "Active" as an example. When we received translations back from the company we're using, they returned "Actif(ve)", as English "Active" translates to masculine "Actif" or feminine "Active". We're unsure of how to display this, and wondered if there are any well established conventions in the web development world.

As far as I see it there are three possible scenarios:

1. We know at development time which noun a given adjective is referring to. In this case we can determine and use the correct gender.
2. We're referring to a user, either directly ("you") or in the third person. Short of making every user have a gender, I don't see a better approach than displaying both, i.e. "Actif(ve)"
3. We are displaying the adjective in isolation, not knowing which noun it's referring to. For example in a table of data, some rows might be dealing with a masculine entity, some feminine.

Scenarios 2 and 3 seem to be the toughest ones. Does anyone have any experience handling these issues? Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: How do similar services in the same language deal with this…? There are probably general norms and cultural customs around this, since everyone in this culture is dealing with the same problem; not just on websites, but on paper forms and such as well…

Comment: Also, not really a technical problem for SO, but perhaps more something for http://ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yeah I appreciate that, I've also posted on Linguistics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

This is complex, because we cannot imagine all the cases, and there is risk to go in "opinion based" answer, so I keep it short and generic.

Usually I prefer to give context in translation (for translator), e.g. providing template: `_("active {user_name}"` (so also the ordering will be correct if languages want different ordering).

Then you may need to change code and template into `_("active {first_name_feminine}")` and `_("active {first_name_masculine}")` (and possibly more for duals, trials, plurals, collectives, honorific, etc.). Note: check that the translator will not mangle the `{}` and the string inside. Usually you need specific export/import scripts. Or I add a note inside the string, and I quickly translate into English removing the note to the translator). Also this can be automated (be creative on using special Unicode characters which should not be used in normal text, to delimit such text).

But if you cannot know the gender, the `Actif(ve)` may be the polite version used in such language. You need a native speaker test, and changes back and forth.